# What is the maximum number of columns of type person/group in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a weird problem with SP-Online.

I have a list with has a higher number of columns of type person/group (20 to be exact). Now if I generate a form for creating/editing items for that list, sharepoint gives an error.

"The webpart cannot be displayed...", and I get a correlation id, which is basically useless to me.

The weird thing is that it does work sometimes*. I also have recreated the whole list and I get the same symptom. The form was created by the designer and it wasn't customized any further in any way.

Did I hit some limit here? Or could there be some other mistake?

Is this a know problem and if so, are there any workarounds? I know I can put multiple people in one field, but that doesn't help me for my use case.

edit: * If I reload the page often enough, the form is displayed correctly. Next time hitting F5 to refresh the page, I get the error again.

I have tried emptying browser caches and tested different Browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by an old known bug on the XSLT transformations handled internally by the engine, at some point the timeout was reduced to one second and with a certain number of columns it starts crashing due the timeout.

This happened with SP 2010 - 2013, I reckon I am actually surprised that this still happens with SharePoint Online but it seems to be the case.

You may be out of luck since it seems this timeout cannot be increased.

reference:

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.nl/2016/01/unable-to-display-this-web-part-after.html

( respect to Mike Smith and after him)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I fear you could very well be correct. It would explain why it does work only sometimes. I excluded some fields from the form manually and now it seems to work. Because I doubt that contacting MS Support would be helpful in any way, I think I will just fill up the values with some client side scripts. Thanks!